# How to convert mysql data into desired json format using php

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I have a question about using a MySQL Query to convert my data into a JSON Object. The Query I have is converting to a JSON Object,

I have learned using array() and trying to create a json which I can use in any mobile application.

mysql data is -

```
state_name      city_name  varient_name price

Uttar Pradesh   Lucknow     varient1    1202
Uttar Pradesh   Lucknow     varient2    1203
Uttar Pradesh   Lucknow     varient3    1204
Delhi           Faridabad   varient1    1206
Delhi           Faridabad   varient2    1207
Delhi           Faridabad   varient3    1208
Delhi           Saket       varient1    1207
Delhi           Saket       varient2    1208
Delhi           Saket       varient3    1209
```

and the response needed in the format -

```
{
    "states": [
        {
            "state_name": "Uttar Pradesh",
            "cities": [
                {
                    "city_name": "Lucknow",
                    "pricedata": [
                        {
                            "varient_name": "varient1",
                            "varient_price": "1201"
                        },
                        {
                            "varient_name": "varient2",
                            "varient_price": "1201"
                        },
                        {
                            "varient_name": "varient3",
                            "varient_price": "1203"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "state_name": "Delhi",
            "cities": [
                {
                    "city_name": "Faridabad",
                    "pricedata": [
                        {
                            "varient_name": "varient1",
                            "varient_price": "1204"
                        },
                        {
                            "varient_name": "varient2",
                            "varient_price": "1205"
                        },
                        {
                            "varient_name": "varient3",
                            "varient_price": "1206"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "city_name": "Saket",
                    "pricedata": [
                        {
                            "varient_name": "varient1",
                            "varient_price": "1207"
                        },
                        {
                            "varient_name": "varient2",
                            "varient_price": "1208"
                        },
                        {
                            "varient_name": "varient3",
                            "varient_price": "1209"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Loop through your data building the array in the format you need. Then use jsonecode() to generate it as json. Post some code of what you have done, and we can help you from there.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @jay can you please share some resource which can Help me to do this .please

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$aR = array();
$req = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($req))
{
    $aR[] = $row;
}
echo '<pre>'.print_r(json_encode($aR),1).'</pre>';
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.